# Redirecting output of mysqldbcompare utility into a text file

Tags: mysql, cmd, output, mysqldbcompare

I am running a command on mysqlulc> prompt on CMD. The command is as below:-

```
mysqluc> mysqldbcompare --server1=root:Password1!@host1 --server2=root:Password1!@host2 teststore:teststore --run-all-tests --changes-for=server2 --difftype=sql
```

I want to redirect the output of this command into a text file.
I have tried redirection operator '>' and also the 'INTO FILE' thing but no success. The 'mysqldbcompare' utility is not accepting any other characters at end of the command.

Please help on this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Putting the redirection in front of the command could work: `>file.txt mysqldbcompare --server1=root... `

Comment: Perhaps some output is going to stderr. Have you tried `>file.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @Liturgist: Thanks for your reply.yes I also tried using this as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and solved by run the mysqldbcompare command under the work bench install folder instead of in the mysqluc command window.

In my case, I run the similar command below under D:\MyTool\mysql-workbench-community-6.2.5-winx64-noinstall\MySQL Workbench 6.2.5 CE (winx64)

```
mysqldbcompare --server1=databaseuser:password@127.0.0.1 --server2=databaseuser:password@10.10.10.10 server1db:server2db --changes-for=server2 -a --difftype=sql >> results.log
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I run this command under Windows 10 elevated command line

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\mysqldiskusage.exe" --server=user:pass@localhost:3306 dbname > "D:\test.txt"
```

It should also works with mysqldbcompare.exe

**Updated:**

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\mysqldbcompare.exe" --server1=user:pass@host --server2=user:pass@host db1:db2 --changes-for=server2 --run-all-tests --skip-data-check --skip-row-count --skip-table-options --difftype=sql > "D:\test.txt"
```

Comment: This works with my Windows 8.1 command prompt. Thank you @sangnandar for saving my time.